# Making AJAX call to MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am trying to make an API call with ajax:

```
svc.authenticateAdmin = function (id, code) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/event/authenticate',
        data: { 'id': id, 'code': code },
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            App.eventBus.publish('authenticationComplete', data);
        }
    });
};
```

The method in the API Controller:

```
[ActionName("All")]
public bool Authenticate(int id, string code)
{
    var repo = new MongoRepository<Event>(_connectionString);
    var entry = repo.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    return entry.AdminPassword == code;
}
```

But I am getting a 404 error: urlstuff/api/event/authenticate?id=123&code=abc 404 (Not Found)

I have copied the implementation from a number of known working calls (that I did not write).  That look like:

```
svc.getEventFromCode = function (code) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/event/',
        data: { 'code': code },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            App.eventBus.publish('loadedEvent', data);
            App.eventBus.publish('errorEventCodeExists');
        },
        error: function () {
            App.eventBus.publish('eventNotFound', code);
        }
    });
};
```

and

```
svc.getEventPage = function (pageNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/event/page/',
        data: { 'pageNumber': pageNumber },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            App.eventBus.publish('loadedNextEventsPage', data);
        }
    });
};
```

But neither has to pass in 2 parameters to the API.  I'm guessing it's something really minor :/

Comment: Can you reach the address `urlstuff/api/event/authenticate?id=123&code=abc 404 ` directly via your browser?

Comment: yes, it redirects to our landing page though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your `url`.

Apparently, ajax interpret `/` at the start of the url to be `root`

When the application is deployed on serverserver, its URL is something like `http://localhost:8080/AppName/`

with `api/event/page/`, ajax resolve the URL to `http://localhost:8080/AppName/api/event/page/` or an url relative to your current directory.

However, with `/api/event/page/`, the URL is resolved to `http://localhost:8080/api/event/page/`

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your action name is called "Authenticate", but you have included the following which will rename the action:

```
[ActionName("All")]
```

This makes the URL

```
/api/event/all
```

Comment: I removed this attribute but I am still getting a 404.

Comment: To clarify, it is a generic "Server responded with..." 404, not the same 404.

Comment: Make sure your URL is correct in your javascript.  Should it be `api/event/authenticate` as you currently have, or should it be `/api/event/authenticate` with the leading slash?  Without the slash, it will be relative to whatever action you're currently running, but I think you want absolute.

Comment: Adding the leading slash gives this new 404:

http://localhost:21968/%20api/event/authenticate?id=109&code=abc

Comment: Why the space before `api` in your URL?

Comment: Sorry I removed it after I too noticed it but the error remains the same.

Comment: I got it working, the controller method needed a [HttpGet] attribute; i don't know why it started becoming a 405 instead of a 404 in the first place though.